# how to convert this to Join AR

Tags: php, yii

how to convert my query to Yii framewor's active record with join?
am having a hard time converting this stuff.

```
        $conn = Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wswebproducts JOIN category_products ON
        category_products.ProductID = wswebproducts.ProductID
        WHERE category_products.catid = :cid";
        $sql = $conn->createCommand($sql);
        $sql->bindValue(':cid',Yii::app()->request->getQuery('cid'));

        $row = $sql->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `category_products relation` in your wswebproducts `model`, joined by ProductID.

```
 public function relations()
{
    return array(
    'category_products' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'category_products(catid, ProductID)'),
    );
}
```

Check out [the manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr), it's awesome :-)

Comment: actually my real problem is, how to load the query in CActiveDataProvider ? :S ...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want and is not working?

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('wswebproducts', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'category_products.catid = :cid',
        'with'=>array('category_products'),
        'params'=>array(':cid'=>Yii::app()->request->getQuery('cid')),
     ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>20,
     ),
));
```

Reference this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider

Comment: I got this error = CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_products.catid' in 'where clause'  ..the wswebproducts table doesn't have a catid column,,if you check my first post, I joined wswebproducts and category_products via their ProductID column,, and the catid column, only exists at the category_products table wherein, it gets filled via getQuery('cid')

Comment: You can try using catid instead of category_products.catid . Also please make sure that you have catid inside your table 'category_products' , the 'category_products' model exists and have catid listed in the top comment area as "@property integer $catid" in the category_products model file